# Исчерпано время ожидания при авторизации через ЕСИА

Tags: php, есиа

Пытаюсь настроить авторизацию личного кабинета через сервис ЕСИА (все необходимые данные системы были зарегистрированы на портале, разрешение на доступ к тестовому сервису получено).
 После отправки запроса на получение авторизационного кода и после ввода на форме данных тестового пользователя ЕСИА,  вместо редиректа на указанный в параметрах адрес, выводит сообщение о том что время ожидания исчерпано.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?
P.S. отправляю данные на адрес https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/ac примерно следующего содержания:

> client_id=MY_ID
>   client_secret=MIIEpzCCA4+gAwI...
>   redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsite.ru%2Fregeca%2Fesia.php
>   scope=openid
>   response_type=code
>   state=f60f1929-b879-4fab-8228-6ae28f8ca7b7
>   access_type=offline
>   timestamp=2018.01.15+13%3A47%3A15+%2B18000

P.P.S. Как я понимаю, проблема возникает из-за значения в переменной timestamp. Web-сервер находится во временной зоне Екатеринбурга, web-сервер также настроен на эту зону.

Comment: Надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится)  Я получила ответ с техподдержки ЕСИА :  обычно такое сообщение означает, что параметр timestamp не валиден, не актуален в большую или меньшую сторону. Системе необходимо синхронизировать время с ресурсом http://www.vniiftri.ru/index.php/ru/services/22-ntp.

Comment: Тогда лучше нажать кнопку "ответить на собственный вопрос".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно такое сообщение означает, что параметр timestamp не валиден, не актуален в большую или меньшую сторону. Системе необходимо синхронизировать время с [ресурсом](http://vniiftri.ru/index.php/ru/services/22-ntp) . Логи можно посмотреть по [адресу](https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/logs/auth/).

P.S. Обнаружила, что для того чтобы получить логи в нормальном виде, к ним нужно заходить к ip-адреса, на котором стоит домен информационной системы (ту, что регистрировали в ЕСИА). По крайней мере, у меня  только так получилось посмотреть ответ на запрос. (Получилось зайти с другого ip, так что скорее всего это был какой-то сбой)

P.P.S. Ошибка с исчерпанием времени ожидания была решена после того как был передан верный параметр timestamp. В соответствии с инструкцией  timestamp имеет формат yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss Z,  в php этот параметр нужно формируется следующим образом:`urlencode(date('Y.m.d H:i:s O'))`

Comment: Можно ещё шлёпнуть галку "правильный ответ"